# Accessing DOM elements in Gtk+ with Webkit < 1.3

Tags: c++, dom, webkit, gtk

I'm using the Gtk+ Webkit bindings to load a page in a WebKitWebView, and I need to access the content of a DIV element on the loaded page.

Until just now I was developing on an Ubuntu Natty machine which had webkit 1.3 which provides the webkit_web_view_get_dom_document() function to gain access to the DOM. But now I've moved over to a Maverick machine this function is not available.

How can I access the content of the loaded page in webkit 1.2?

I don't need to have full access to the DOM, just the HTML content of the view would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the old trick where you execute Javascript that sets the WebView's title with the div contents, and then read it from there? Similar to how we get around DOM stuff in [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/wiki/HowDoI).